# EF Core exception when running add-migration statement with PublishAot flag set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-8.0

I created a new Web API project (AOT), after I created the basic tables and the basic settings, I needed to create my first migration  `Add-Migration InitialCreate;` but I get an exception:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Model building is not supported when publishing with NativeAOT. Use a compiled model.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance for the different patterns supported at design time.

My `ApplicationDbContext` code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    } 

    public DbSet<Department>? Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Unit>? Units { get; set; } 
}
```

My `Program.cs` is:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateSlimBuilder(args);
var ConnectionString = "Connection";
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x =>
{
    x.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolverChain.Insert(0, AppJsonSerializerContext.Default);
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Provider and version information:

- EF Core v8.0.0
- Database provider: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
- Target framework: .NET 8.0
- Operating system: Windows 10
- IDE: Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3

Comment: Probably you should follow exception information and introduce [Compiled Model](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/misc/compiled-models)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv as a comment on GitHub :
"EF is not yet compatible with NativeAOT; various work has been done to prepare for this, but 8.0 does not yet support it. We plan to deliver at least some experimental support in 9.0."

Comment: Well, you have to avoid applying migrations with NativeAOT publishing. Publish Migrations as separated project as regular .NET library.

Comment: That's what I do, thanks man.